# Three consecutive integers with power of 5 mod 11

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $(n - 1)$, $n$ and $(n + 1)$ be three consecutive integers, and $(n - 1)^5 \equiv n^5 \equiv (n + 1)^5 \equiv a \pmod{11}$, what are the possible values of $a$?

I know the facts that $3^5 \equiv 4^5 \equiv 5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ and $6^5 \equiv 7^5 \equiv 8^5 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$ are two solutions, however, is there a way to actually solve this equation?

Comment: Since $n^5 \text{ mod } 11 = (n \text{ mod } 11)^5$, the easiest way through it is to explicitly examine $0^5, 1^5, \ldots, 10^5$.

Comment: What are the possible values of $n^5$ modulo $11$? There are only three possible values at all.

Comment: I see, Fermat tells us that $n^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, so if n is coprime to 11, $n^5$ modulo 11 could have only two values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is sufficiently to check the numbers $-5,-4,\ldots,4,5$.